# Wordpress Plugin Dynamic Error Page

Tags: php, plugins, filter, wordpress

What action or filter can I use in a Wordpress plugin to dynamically replace the **contents** (i.e. not the header or footer) of a 404 error page?

Basically I'm looking for a 404 error page equivalent for `the_content` [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), which will filter the contents of an existing page.

Thank you for your time.

**Note:** I know I can manually modify the 404 error page for the current theme, but that is not the effect I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Nice question but kind of tricky, because there seems to be no common element in a `404.php` template where we can hook in an universal way... Oh, an idea poped, will research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this WordPress Answer: [How to control output of custom post type without modifying theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75728/12615)

Plugin file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin 404 Page
Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539884
Description: Use the plugin's template file to render a custom 404.php
Author: brasofilo
Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
Version: 2013.26.01
License: GPLv2
*/
class Universal_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->url = plugins_url( '', __FILE__ );   
        $this->path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
   }

    public function init() 
    {
        add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'template_404' ) );
    }

    public function template_404( $template ) 
    {
        if ( is_404() )
            $template = $this->path . '/404.php';

        return $template;
    }
}

$so_14539884 = new Universal_Template();
```

And in the plugin folder, a file named `404.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found).
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        MY 404!
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the content of 404.php file. If this file contains static text, like

```
_e( 'It seems we can&rsquo;t find what you&rsquo;re looking for...', 'twentyeleven' );
```

you can add your own filter

```
apply_filters( 'my_404_content', 'Default 404 message' );
```

and in functions.php (or in plugin)

```
add_filter( 'my_404_content', 'replace_404_message' );
function replace_404_message($message) {
    return 'Error 404 - '.$message;
}
```

If 404.php uses built-in WP functions to display page content, you should check what filters they are supported.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to add a `the_content` filter with a conditional [`is_404`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) section:

```
function content_404($content) {
  if (is_404()) {
    // do some stuff with $content
  }
  // no matter what,
  return $content;
} 

add_filter( 'the_content', 'content_404' );
```

Note that this does assume that the `404.php` page template has a `the_content` template tag in place.

Comment: Interesting... unfortunately, it appears as though too many `404.php` templates do not include the `the_content` template tag. Thank you for your input, anyway!